# Precision of Rational Approximation to $\pi$ versus series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

For $n\geq 1$, let:

$$
a_n = \text{min} \lbrace{|\sin(k)|: 1\leq k\leq n} \rbrace
$$

So that $a_1=\sin(1)$,$a_2=\sin(1)$,$a_3=\sin(3)$,$a_4=\sin(3)$, $a_5=\sin(3)$ and so on.

And let:
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k
$$

The questions:

1-Does $a_n$ converge?  (yes, proven in a comment by  Xander Henderson)

2-What is the limit of $a_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity? (proven to be zero by Matt F. in his answer)

3-Does $S_n$ converge? (Still open)

I believe this can be related to the precision of rational approximations of $\pi$ because for some integer $a$ there exists $b\in]0,\pi[$ such that:

$$
n= a\pi+b
$$ 
Then:
$$
|\sin(n)|=|\sin(a\pi+b)| = |\sin(b)|
$$ 
And:
$$
\pi = \frac{n}{a}-\frac{b}{a}
$$

So $n/a$ is a rational approximation of $\pi$ with error smaller than $\pi/a$ in absolute value. But since $b$ is in the interval ]0,\pi[ (cannot be zero because $\pi$ is irrational), then the sequence is basically the value of the smallest $b$ found for $k\leq n$.

My guess is that the sequence converges to zero, even if it never reaches zero (just like a geometric progression). I would also believe the series is convergent, but these would depend on how fast the accuracy of the rational approximations to $\pi$ grows with respect to their denominator.

Comment: $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded below by zero.  It must converge.  Indeed, it converges to zero, though it takes some work to show this.

Comment: Your question 3 is almost certainly unsolved, since it relates closely to the (unknown) [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) of $\pi$. A proof that $S_n$ was divergent would also prove that $\pi$ had irrationality measure $2$, so we certainly don't have that. A proof that $S_n$ was convergent technically wouldn't imply anything about the irrationality measure of $\pi$, but still seems unlikely to exist to me.

Comment: As others have said, the answer to 1 and 2 are fairly simple. As for 3, I think an easier question would be to ask about the sum of the unique values of $a_n$ (of which the first four are $\sin(1),\sin(2),\sin(3)$ and then $|\sin(22)|$)

Comment: @Ian that's an interesting suggestion. But if your proposed sum were to diverge, then so would $S_n$, however, if your proposed sum were to converge, nothing could be said about $S_n$, it adds information, but is not the same the question.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is not equivalent to this one.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes.
2. The $a_n$ converge to $0$.  Proof:  Let $a = \liminf a_n$.  If $a>0$ then the integers mod $\pi$ would have density $0$ in the interval $(0, \arcsin(a))$, contradicting [equidistribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem).
3. The $S_n$ probably do not converge, using an analogy that analytic number theorists can probably make rigorous.  Consider $X_i$ equidistributed on $[0, \pi]$, which is the same as the limiting distribution of the integers mod $\pi$.  Let $$a’_n= \min(\{|\sin(X_i)|: 1\le i \le n\}),$$ $$E[a’_n] \sim \sin\left(\frac\pi{2(n+1)}\right),$$
   since the expected quantile of the minimum is $1/(n+1)$. The expected sum of these $a’_n$ does not converge, and by analogy, $S_n$ should not converge either.

Comment: Dear @Matt F. That's an interesting approach, which does add some light to the problem, though I guess you know it is not conclusive. I'd like to ask for a clarification on point 2: Equidistribution says the probability density of $n \pi \, \text{mod} \, 1$ is constant (and uniform). But the sequence I propose speaks about $n  \,\text{mod} \, \pi$. How do link those two cases?

Comment: @Mefitico Equidistribution says $nb \mod 1$ is equidistributed for any irrational $b$.  So take $b=1/\pi$; then $n/\pi \mod 1$ is equidistributed, and this is just a rescaling of $n \mod \pi$.

Comment: I've awarded the bonus to this answer which indeed has valuable insight, although the original problem still lacks a definitive solution.